# Is it possible to have a vs2010 vsix check for updates locally?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, extensibility, vsix

I'm writing a project structure and code analysis extension for visual studio at work. The project can not be published to the Visual Studio Extensions Gallery.

Is there any way to manage updates and deployment built in to visual studio so that a team can use the extension and get the update prompts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not a supported operation on Visual Studio 2010.  I just verified this with the extension manager team.

Comment: @Maslow, I agree.  I hope it's changed in a future version.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can do this now with [Private Galleries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266746.aspx)!

[image]