# VS 2010 Custom Private Extension

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have written a custom Visual Studio 2010 extension that helps developers at the company I work with with some of our development standards.  Obviously, this is specific to this company and I would not want to upload it to the public gallery.

My question is, how can I have VS detect updates for it?  Everything I saw said to upload it to the VS Public gallery and VS would automatically detect the updates.  Are there any other built in options?  I am trying to avoid coding something custom for it...

Comment: Probably a dupe of this question from yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570406/is-it-possible-to-have-a-vs2010-vsix-check-for-updates-locally

Comment: please check the link Noah added, I just answered the question there

Answer (score 0):

I know its a bit late now and VS 2012 and above already support private gallery.
But if you are still looking to host private gallery for VS2010, then check out this [project](http://vsprivategallery.codeplex.com/).