# How do I make my SideWaffle extension (vsix) check for updates?

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix, sidewaffle

I've used SideWaffle to create a VSIX ([source here](https://github.com/allenrice/DriveTimeScaffolding)) that contains project templates and scaffolders.  However, to update the installed VSIX, I've been uninstalling the previous version and installing the new version manually.

Is there any support for integrating into Visual Studio's built in "Extensions and Updates" UI to handle updates for my VSIX?

I'm not sure if this is independent of SideWaffle or not.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Ah, of course, it looks like this is using the VisualStudioGallery... looks like this person was on the right track, with trying to do it locally: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570406/is-it-possible-to-have-a-vs2010-vsix-check-for-updates-locally

Comment: Dumb question: why not just increment the version number and let the built-in support work?

Comment: Not a dumb question :)  We already update the version number, but for visual studio to actually see that new version, it has to be deployed somewhere that visual studio can find it.  We haven't been deploying this to the VisualStudioGallery.  We're going to deploy it to a local gallery now

Comment: Yep local gallery would be the good way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to deploy your extension somewhere that Visual Studio knows about.  This can be the public [Visual Studio Gallery site](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/) or a [Private Gallery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266746.aspx)

If you want to go down the Private Gallery route, configure your Visual Studio like so

[image]